# What is the recommended doctrine relationship between these tables?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to model the following tables in Doctrine2:

- Table 1. Items (products)
- Table 2. Categories
- Table 3. ItemsToCategories (id, item_id, category_id)

An item can be in many categories. A category can have many items. Restructuring the data is (currently) not an option and I did not design the schema.

What is the recommended way to model this many-to-many association with a join table. The [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) does not seem to cover this exact case and I'm keen to hear from others who have done something similar with Doctrine2 and / or Symfony (2.4)

Answer (score 1):

Create two entities: `Item` and `Category`:

```
<?php

namespace YourApplication\Bundle\DatabaseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Categories")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Item", inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ItemsToCategories")
     */
    protected $items;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}

<?php

namespace YourApplication\Bundle\DatabaseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Items")
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="items")
     */
    protected $items;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->items = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Since a category *owns* the items and the items *are owned* by the categories, `Category` will be the owning side and `Item` will be the inverse side of the relationship.